# How to render Swig templates with Express 4?

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I am not able to use Swig templates with Express for Node. 
I get the following error :

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
```

The Swig templates are not being compiled into .html files

My code is below :

```
var express = require('express');
var cons = require('consolidate');
var swig = require('swig');
var app = express();

//Set template engine
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')


// Disable Express's and Swig Cache
app.set('view cache', false);
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {'title': 'Design'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: you don't want to rename your template?

Comment: I am sorry @Matteo I don't understand.

Comment: Your code works fine if you create the file `views/index.html`

Comment: Yes. I want to use SWIG templates. Swig should compile `index.swig` to `index.html` which should work fine. The problem is `index.swig` is not compiled.

Comment: sorry i'm pretty new to the language but i can't find any reference to compiling swig pages

Comment: Can you post the index.swig files? Have you tried to simply rename it to index.html?

Comment: The swig contents will be ~hello {{title}}~ and this should compile to ~hello Design~

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your needed, i put your template code in a `views/index.html ` and then print me `~hello Design` probably i'm too newbie. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. In order to use swig templates with the `swig` extension working you can follow the [swig Docs](http://thunf.me/swig/docs/#express) and then replace the two following lines with

    `app.engine('html', cons.swig);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');`
 with

    `app.engine('swig',swig.renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');`

Should look something like this.

```js
var express = require('express');
var swig = require('swig');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
// This is where all the magic happens!
app.engine('swig', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'swig');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view cache', false);
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });
```

[Expressjs 4.x docs app.engine](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.engine)
The app.engine takes a extension and a callback. So to all files found with the `swig` extension have a callback of `swig.renderFile`. Each file with generated to HTML.

[Expressjs 4.x docs app.set](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set)
Setting the `view engine`to `swig` is setting the default engine extension to use when omitted. Were also saying that all the views can be found in the `/blaha/blaha/blah/views` directory.

NOTE: All files in the views directory must end int `.swig`. 
So just a friendly reminder make sure when you "include" or reference another template you must put the filename and extension it the path. ex: `layout.swig`. I hope this gets your project working.

Answer (score 2):

As explained here:

http://mherman.org/blog/2015/08/23/primer-on-swig-templating/#.VhWxVvlVhBc

Simply use `.html` files instead of `.swig` files. I don't know where you got the idea of using `.swig` files. Maybe an older version? I dunno. The current Swig's documentation Basic Usage shows using a `.html` file as well:

http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/

If you rename your `index.swig` to `index.html` I would expect it to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i think it's more semantic to store your templates as .swig files, if you using SWIG as template engine. So, all you need is set 'swig' as engine:

```
// view engine setup
app.engine('swig', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'swig');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Then you can store your views like ./views/layout.swig

Answer (score 0):

for latest version of swig we need to include swig package which needed to installed through package manager or package.json file

`var express = require('express');`

`var swig = require('swig');`

`var app = express();`

`// Here we need to set up and engine as per latest version of swig
  //for latest version of swig we need to include swig package which                //needed to installed through package manager or package.json file`

`app.engine('swig', swig.renderFile);`

`app.set('view engine', 'swig');`

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

`app.set('view cache', false);`

`swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });`
  `//Here we are setting cache defaults to false.`

`